# Property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto not working as expected (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ddl

what I want to achieve:

Write a little class that creates a schema during startup. If the schema exists, it should be dropped and re-created.

I have to say I'm quite new to Hibernate, so chances are the error is on my side.

The program runs fine the first time, but the second time I get an exception (see below) that the table already exists (which is true, but I was expecting Hibernate to delete and then re-create it.

My configuration:

Hibernate 5.4.20, MySQL 5.7.9, MyISAM (same result on InnoDB btw.), MS Windows 10 (64 bit).

Tried already every MySQLDialect, MYSQL5Dialect & MySQL57Dialect - same result.

Here's the code:

```
public class HibernateCreateRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
        settings.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //settings.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");
        settings.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stats_test?serverTimezone=UTC");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
        settings.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        settings.put("show_sql", "true");

        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(settings)
                        .build());

        metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(CaseAndResult.class);
        metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(CaseObject.class);
        metadataSources.buildMetadata();

        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();;

        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
        schemaExport.setHaltOnError(true)
            .setFormat(true)
            .setDelimiter(";")
            .setOutputFile("db-schema.sql")
            .createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE, TargetType.STDOUT), metadata);
    }
```

}

And this is the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Halting on error : Error executing DDL "
    create table CASEANDRESULT (
       CASEID varchar(255) not null,
        ASSESSMENTDATE datetime,
        CARRESULTLEVELID integer,
        CARRESULTLEVELNAME varchar(255),
        CASEMODE varchar(255),
        COMPLETE TINYINT,
        LOCALE varchar(255),
        NUMBEROFCHANGEASSESSCYCLES varchar(255),
        NUMBEROFSOURCECHANGES integer,
        PATCHNAME varchar(255),
        POLICYCANBEISSUED TINYINT,
        VERSIONNAME varchar(255),
        primary key (CASEID)
    ) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerHaltImpl.handleException(ExceptionHandlerHaltImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.doExecution(SchemaExport.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.createOnly(SchemaExport.java:224)
    at com.genre.star.database.HibernateCreateRunner.main(HibernateCreateRunner.java:46)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table CASEANDRESULT (
       CASEID varchar(255) not null,
        ASSESSMENTDATE datetime,
        CARRESULTLEVELID integer,
        CARRESULTLEVELNAME varchar(255),
        CASEMODE varchar(255),
        COMPLETE TINYINT,
        LOCALE varchar(255),
        NUMBEROFCHANGEASSESSCYCLES varchar(255),
        NUMBEROFSOURCECHANGES integer,
        PATCHNAME varchar(255),
        POLICYCANBEISSUED TINYINT,
        VERSIONNAME varchar(255),
        primary key (CASEID)
    ) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'caseandresult' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
```

Any hints very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `createOnly` which only creates the schema, and the table already exists

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'caseandresult' already exists
```

If you want to drop the schema first, you should call `SchemaExport.execute` with action `BOTH`

Comment: Hi @paranoidAndroid, this did the trick & bumped me into the right direction. Besides your suggestion there's also another solution: Instead of "createOnly" calling "create" resolves the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: yes, you're right, create() basically calls execute with BOTH as action

Answer (score 0):

You get with your code following `Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`
so use only following lenghth

```
create table CASEANDRESULT8 (
   CASEID varchar(250) not null,
    ASSESSMENTDATE datetime,
    CARRESULTLEVELID integer,
    CARRESULTLEVELNAME varchar(255),
    CASEMODE varchar(255),
    COMPLETE TINYINT,
    LOCALE varchar(255),
    NUMBEROFCHANGEASSESSCYCLES varchar(255),
    NUMBEROFSOURCECHANGES integer,
    PATCHNAME varchar(255),
    POLICYCANBEISSUED TINYINT,
    VERSIONNAME varchar(255),
    primary key (CASEID)
) engine=MyISAM
```